# read.ts(6133) Module '"../../../node_modules/rxjs/observable/combineLatest"' has no exported member 'combineLatest'.ts(2305)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rxjs

How to combine Observables by combineLatest. combineLatest is not defined

I am using angular js 7.I want to marge tow query string parameter but when I write the obserable.combinelaste([]) then it will give en error.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of, observable } from 'rxjs'
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/observable/combineLatest';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-githubfollowers',
  templateUrl: './githubfollowers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./githubfollowers.component.css']
})
export class GithubfollowersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private rout:ActivatedRoute ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    Observable.combineLatest([  this.rout.paramMap,
  this.rout.queryParamMap

    ]);

    this.rout.paramMap.subscribe(prams=>{

    });
    this.rout.queryParamMap.subscribe(prams=>{

    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You import is wrong. You used the import for RXJS v5.

For RxJS v6+, you should use this import :

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```

To solve the following error message :

> ngOnInit() { Observable.combineLatest([ this.rout.paramMap,
>   this.rout.queryParamMap ]); Property 'combineLatest' does not exist on
>   type 'typeof Observable

You can use `combineLatest` like this :

```
combineLatest(this.rout.paramMap, this.rout.queryParamMap)
```

And you probably have to spend some time to read how to use it: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: when I add this then show ngOnInit() {
     Observable.combineLatest([
     this.rout.paramMap,
     this.rout.queryParamMap

     ]);        Property 'combineLatest' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable

Comment: I am also using angular js7